# I want to read the saved document but i cant i tried changing it to .txt, .docx still not working

Tags: java, database, fileoutputstream

here is my code. i can use the read object properly but i really want to read the saved document 
myself not the hieroglyphics ¬í sr java.lang.BooleanÍ r€Õœúî Z valuexpsr 
java.lang.Integerâ ¤÷‡8 I valuexr java.lang.Number†¬•”à‹  xp      sq ~ 
 –sq ~   £t Geromet ont earthsr java.util.ArrayListxÒ™Ça I sizexp   w
t onet twot threet fourt fivex

```
public class SaveObjects{
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        boolean powerSwitch = true;
        int x = 9, y=150, z = 675;
        String name ="Gerome",setting ="on",planet="earth";
        ArrayList stuff = new ArrayList();
        stuff.add("one");
        stuff.add("two");
        stuff.add("three");
        stuff.add("four");
        stuff.add("five");

        try {
            FileOutputStream saveFile = new FileOutputStream(name+".sav");

            ObjectOutputStream save = new ObjectOutputStream(saveFile);

            save.writeObject(powerSwitch);
            save.writeObject(x);
            save.writeObject(y);
            save.writeObject(z);
            save.writeObject(name);
            save.writeObject(setting);
            save.writeObject(planet);
            save.writeObject(stuff);


            save.close();
        }
```

any suggestions? thanks a lot :D

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. Do you want to read the object data as regular text? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Could you also post the way you read from input stream?

Are you casting the input to proper types while reading from file?

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply outputting text, rather than any binary data, try this.

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(name+".sav");
```